# Can't Build off of a pre-docked port in the VAB

Tags: kerbal-space-program

I have seen some videos of people creating ships that launch with smaller ships all in one go. Those ships are often docked with docking ports, which are done from the VAB.
I know that the ports need to face each-other in order to be docked, but when I move and rotate them to face each-other so they are pre-docked, I cannot build things up off of them.
For example, I cannot seem to get a MK1 command pod attached to a clamp-o-tron on top to be rotated to match another clamp-o-tron on the main booster, and then put a fuel tank on top of that.
They won't snap to the top, so the whole thing in super wonky.

am I just supposed to manually rotate and translate all of the parts that are on top?

Comment: are you placing *then* rotating or rotating *then* placing

Comment: I placed then rotated then placed again.

Comment: Strangest thing. It seems to have started working when I tried a new one.
The process I took to get it to work was:
- Add one of the pods I want
- Add a docking port on top with snap
- add a docking port on bottom with snap
- put the 2nd pod I want on bottom
- rotate upside-down and translate down
- place the docking port so that the two ports are facing each-other
- build fuel tanks on top, and fuel tanks on bottom

This wasn't working the first time I tried it where there was just no nod snap at all when trying to put fuel on top.
Not sure what changed

Answer (score 2):

You want to first select the part in the SPH/VAB, then press and hold the [Modifier key](https://wiki.kerbalspaceprogram.com/wiki/Key_bindings#Modifier_key). This is <kbd>Alt</kbd> on Windows and disables surface attachment, forcing to use the nodes:

> Mod (hold) - Disable surface attach/exclusively use node attach - Since 0.25.0

Answer (score 0):

Attachment of stuff to parts which support both surface attachment and node attachment is wonky (e.g. to the docking port).

If you pick up a part in the VAB and try to attach it by pointing at the docking port, it will default to surface attachment. I guess this is what is causing the problems.

To make it use node attachment (the one you want), you have to sort of hover the part in the right place without pointing at the docking port.

I've attached an image with the cursor position indicated in red showing how I usually do it. :)

[image: Part positioning]

Comment: So, I was able to get that far before asking the question. The issue happens after that, where the parts don't want to attach to the now upside-down parts.